# How to monitor bash/zsh prompt input?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I need to view the user's prompt input in a background script. (in both zsh and bash).

For example if the user has typed

```
[3:30pm@home]> ssh user@23.23.23.23 ls -alh
```

My background process needs the string "ssh user@23.23.23.23 ls -alh" before they press enter.

$PS1 has the prompt string, but not the user input.

Is this possible?

For background, the overall goal is to take user's partial input and translate shell to english. For example, if I were to type `ls -al`, my $PS1 or $PS2 would change to say "list all files in a long format in the current directory". So, if someone didn't exactly remember if -X or -x enabled X11 forwarding with `ssh`, they can type it and see if the plain language english translation matches their expectations.

I want it to be a zsh plugin, or a script that people toss into the `rc` files, so there can't be anything too major done.

Comment: You can probably use a `DEBUG` trap in `bash`, and `zle`, IIRC, has the ability to edit a command line before actually executing it. This sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), though. Why do you need to see the input?

Comment: Sounds like very suspicious behaviour

Comment: It does sound suspicious, @glenn-jackman, but I want to create a script that will live translate shell commands into plain english. So when you're at the prompt typing normal your normal stuff, like "tar -xvf" it will show (and update live as you type further) "extract the archive at _____, verbosely".  I have a repo here with the beginnings of the shell to english translation https://github.com/tennysonholloway/shell-to-english

Comment: you might want to have a look at the [tag:fish] shell -- it has a very nice dynamic "autosuggestion" feature that changes as you type. Mind you, that's built into the shell, not added on top. If I was tasked with this project, I'd look at using [tag:expect]

Comment: trying to make it into a plugin people can drop into their existing bash/zsh setup without much damage, so i think using `DEBUG` traps is out of the cards. I have looked at fish, but am finding the same problems; there's no real endpoint exposed (that i can find) to get the partial user prompt input.

Comment: You can override the `self-insert` widget and read `$BUFFER`, but unless very carefully coded, it is likely to interfere with other widgets and break, `url-quote-magic` being one. That covers part of the problem.

Comment: The full solution would require overriding almost every widget. [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/master/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh) and [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/master/autosuggestions.zsh) kind of do exactly that, so you can take a look (your problem is much simpler though, because you don't manipulate the buffer), but I'm not at all happy with their implementations (I can't suggest something better though), which when used together becomes utterly unmanageable and very fragile.

Comment: Also note that `$BUFFER` need not be user input (say when you have `predict-on` or zsh-autosuggestions as mentioned above), so overall it's a very hard problem to solve. However, if you're working with a controlled environment where users are not allowed to install plugins and/or define custom widgets (i.e., you're the only one in town), then it's probably okay. Looks like the environments you're in can be assumed to be controlled anyway, since  your tool is obviously only for beginners... (But beware that it's very hard to debug things with beginners.)

Comment: @4ae1e1 thank you for linking those zsh plugins, I think I'll be able to figure it out by looking at their sources.

Comment: Now that I think about it, a good starting point might be `predict-on` that I mentioned above: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/predict-on, which is much less aggressive, and whose code quality is agreed upon, as seen from being accepted into contrib. I still think zsh-syntax-highlighting and zsh-autosuggestions's alias/override-everything approach is madness, and in my brief experiences with them I could not reconcile my personal setup with their hell of aliases/overrides.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the input in real time ? or at least just before the line is accepted ?

For the last option, in zsh there is a widget `accept-line` that is triggered when the input line is accepted. You can override the default widget with you own, like this :

```
function accept-line
{
    #here, send the input to your script
    yourscript "$BUFFER"

    # ... do something here if you want

    # trigger the real widget to accept the line and run the input
    zle .accept-line
}
# register your new accept-line widget to replace the builtin one
zle -N accept-line
```

Here I used the name `accept-line` but if you want to name your override function `my_superOverride` you can override the default widget at the end with :

```
zle -N accept-line my_superOverride
```